# Can't identify this component on a speed control hand tool

Tags: identification, motor-controller

[image]This component in orange looks like a rectifier bridge or similar. The potentiometer output is feeding this device and also the Gate of the Triac. I change the triac but speed control is still 100%. Anyone can feed replacement info on this part?

The back of the board shows 7 terminals if this could help.

[image]

Comment: could be a relay... look for other markings ... please add a picture of the other side of the PCB

Comment: jsotola :   I hope the back can help identify the component.

Comment: why do you think that the component is defective? ... the solder joints look awful ... fix that first

Comment: Potentiometer seems to work fine in ohms but i don't see a voltage drop from the wiper. when I test it on the board with power supply 25 dc.  Yellow capacitor is showing .2 uf instead of 0,47uf (removed from the board for testing).  I wonder what a bad capacitor would affect the flow of current to the gate? Regardless of potentiometer position, the  motor is always at full speed.

Comment: I am new at this forum. Here's the closest diag that looks like the board : https://electronicsarea.com/dimmer-ac-motor-speed-controller/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a (likely potted) module with a PCB sticking out of the end. That, in turn, fits in a slot in the power PCB and is soldered. Probably contains low power circuitry.

It's no doubt a proprietary module and if it's actually at fault repair choices will be limited.

Comment: Spehro: To bad. I was hoping to fix it. Hand tool variable speed. Tks

Comment: As jsotola said, it's not necessarily the problem. Usually it's a power component or something mechanical. Rock that part gently and look at the joints to see if the connections are broken- that's a dubious method of assembly for a rugged application. Also clean the board around those connections with isopropanol. Maybe it got wet.

Comment: good point. I redone soldering. no changes. Also use Iso alcool.  I will have to check with  Microscope and replace capacitor